# How to use websocket with Restlet framework?

Tags: java, restlet, java-websocket

We have a web server written in Restlet framework, now we want to implement websocket to replace long polling design which cause some performance issue.
Checked RestLet's forum and document, looks websocket is no support yet and even not in schedule.And we don't want to replace Restlet with some other frame work since it will be big change, now we comes out some design proposals, and not sure which one is best:

- Start another Jetty server, and use Jetty's websocket lib to handle websocket connection;

  - Prons:No need self develop websocket lib base on Restlet;
  - Cons: Need have 2 server listening on different ports.
- Develop our own websocket lib based on Restlet:

  - Prons: No need start second server;
  - Cons: Big development effort.

We are still investigating, appreciate for any sharing and valuable comments, thanks!!

Comment: use some websocket lib, run websocket server in the same VM as the restlet, on a different port.

Comment: You mean in Apache, config mod_proxy to redirect request to different port?

Comment: What framework are you using? Based on the info you gave @bayou.io 's answer seems very reasonable - and yes, you could configure Apache to proxy (not redirect) to the appropriate port.

Comment: We are using RestLet framework for restfulApi.
Thanks to all of you, I'm trying to investigating on Apache proxy now.
Looks RestLet are using port 8182, and we already has a proxy config like:

- httpConfig:
  - ProxyPass /api http://localhost:8182/api retry=1
  - ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:8182/api
I'm thinking start another JVM to create a jetty websocket server listen to some other port like 9120, and add proxy config in Apache side.

Comment: There is nothing RESTFul about websockets. Consider using a less focused API if you want to use websockets such as the Servlet API and a Servlet container. It really isn't that hard to Gson your POJOs and write them out over an HTTP response.

Comment: @bhspencer a side note, it would be great if Restlet supports WebSocket, not that is it "restful" but WebSocket will allow Restlet-based applications more reactive, for example, backend frameworks are Restful and they use WebSocket to for real-time data, for example, subscribing to changes in a domain object or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Websockets are not supported yet in the Restlet framework, there is an issue opened : https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/893

Comment: Hopefully, Restlet will be able to support Websocket even as an extension. Most Java frameworks now are reactive and Restlet is still way behind reactive.